# How do I do definite integrals in jupyter 6.01

Tags: jupyter, sympy

```
x=symbols('x')
(print) integrate(.6*x, (x,pi/3,3*pi/2))
                ^
Syntaxerror:invalid syntax
```

Always gives me an error and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Error code is showing up for line 2. Using sympy.

Comment: syntax error is carrot pointing to the "e" in integrate

Comment: Repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697680/how-do-i-do-definite-integrals-on-jupyter-6-01

Comment: To call print, use `print(integrate(.6*x, (x,pi/3,3*pi/2)))`.   Writing `(print) integrate` is invalid Python syntax. In an interactive session, or in Jupyter you can also just write `integrate(.6*x, (x,pi/3,3*pi/2))` as the last command, and it will display the calculated expression.

Comment: Note that instead of posting a new question, it is highly recommended editing the original question and adding more information.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

print(integrate(.6*x, (x, pi/3, 3*pi/2)))
```

If you do not want the decimal expression, you can put

```
print(integrate(Rational(6, 10)*x, (x, pi/3, 3*pi/2)))
```